# Laravel 8 - two foreign key from the users table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design, laravel-8

I want to create application where two people can create meeting room.
But I don't know how to make schema in Laravel.

I tried to create like this:

```
Schema::create('appointments_tables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id2');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); 
            $table->foreign('user_id2')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');      
            $table->datetime('start');
    });
}
```

Is it the right way how to do it?

Comment: this is correct if there can only be max two people in the room

Comment: @NadirAbbas Yes, only for two people, so I don't need another table. :) Thank you! 

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's correct.

You can also use the artisan command "php artisan make:migration".

Here's the details on that command help flag:

$ php artisan -help make:migration

Description:

Create a new migration file

Usage:

make:migration [options] [--]

Arguments:

name                   The name of the migration

Options:

```
  --create[=CREATE]  The table to be created
  --table[=TABLE]    The table to migrate
  --path[=PATH]      The location where the migration file should be created
  --realpath         Indicate any provided migration file paths are pre-resolved absolute paths
  --fullpath         Output the full path of the migration
```

-h, --help             Display this help message
-q, --quiet            Do not output any message
-V, --version          Display this application version
--ansi             Force ANSI output
--no-ansi          Disable ANSI output
-n, --no-interaction   Do not ask any interactive question
--env[=ENV]        The environment the command should run under
-v|vv|vvv, --verbose   Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table call appointments where you store the date and create a pivot table call appointment_user where you store the user_id and appointment_id and can add a column in the pivot table call role.

For more information search about many to many relations in Laravel Docs